# (left) Shift Semigroup and operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

I am reading some lecture notes on strongly continuous semigroups. I am having difficulty understanding an example:
$$X = BUC(\mathbb{R}) := \{f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R : f \text{ is uniformly continuous and bounded}\} $$
with supremum norm $$\|f\|_{\infty} = \sup _{s \in \mathbb R}|f(s)|$$
$T(t)$ is the shift semigroup; $T(t)f(s) = f(t+s)$, which is indeed a strongly continuous semigroup.
Then it says $T(t)$ is not continuous for the operator norm.
How can it be strongly continuous semigroup on X but not continuous for the operator norm?
I mean it is obviously bounded; what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strongly continuous means
$$
\forall x: \quad \lim_{t\to0}\|T(t)x-x\|_X \to 0,
$$
while continuity in operator norm means $\|T(t)-Id\|_{\mathcal L(X,X)}\to 0$, which is equivalent to
$$
\lim_{t\to0} \sup_{x: \|x\|\le1} \|T(t)x-x\|_X \to 0,
$$
in the second case the convergence has to be uniform with respect to $x$.

In your example, the first property is a consequence of uniform continuity of $x\in X$. To show that the second property is not fulfilled, it is enought to construct for each $\epsilon>0$ a function $x\in X$ such that $\|T(t)x-x\|>\epsilon$. This can be achieved using $x(s):=\max(-1,\min(ns,1))$ for sufficiently large $n$.